# Finding circumference without using $\pi$

Tags: geometry, circles

If the area of a circle is $254.34\ldots\text{ cm}^2$ it has a diameter of $18\text{ cm}$, is it possible to find the circumference without using or making the irrational constant Pi ($\pi=3,1415926535\ldots)$ in any way at all, and if it is possible, how?

To find the area of $254.34$ I used $\pi$ as $3.14$ in shorthand. The formula you give should allow me to find the Circumference as $56.52\text{ cm}$ (as this also uses $\pi$ as 3.14)

Sorry! There was a mistake in the question!

Comment: Do you want to avoid using value of $\pi$ or the concept of $\pi$ and all the formulas that contain $\pi$?

Comment: The area of a circle needs to be in square linear units; square cm instead of cm. The area cannot be 279.46 cm.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but all the answers use $\pi$ in some way... Just for fun, consider using the method [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/circle-area-by-sectors.html). you know the area of the "rectangle" there and one side length. You can then compute the other side length and thus find the circumference.

Comment: @DanielK Did you mean to use $\pi = 2.14$?

Comment: Your data are inconsistent.  A radius of 9 cm gives an area of $81 \pi \approx 254.47$ and a circumference of $\approx 56.549$

Comment: @DavidMitra it seems to me that the method you refer to is just a geometric approach to do exactly the same thing that we did with algebraic manipulation. Do you disagree?

Comment: @JonathanChristensen Not quite. Though a limit process is needed, wouldn't the argument not reference $\pi$ at all?

Comment: @anorton Sorry that was a typo. Fixed some things there. Pi = 3.14 in this equation

Comment: @DanielK I've edited my answer to use 254.34, which makes it work out perfectly.

Comment: @DavidMitra Ok, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 29):

Consider a $n$ sided regular polygon as shown in the figure below.
[image]

Let the diameter of the polygon as shown be $d$ and the side of the polygon be $a$. Then the area of the triangle as shown in the figure is $$T = \dfrac12 \times a \times \dfrac{d}2 = \dfrac{ad}4$$
The perimeter of the polygon is $$P = na,$$ while the area of the polygon is $$A = nT = \dfrac{nad}4.$$ Hence, we get that $$A = \dfrac{Pd}4$$
Letting the number of sides $n$ tend to infinity, the polygon "tends" to a circle and we get that
$$\text{Area of the circle} = \dfrac{\text{Circumference }\times \text{ diameter}}4$$
or to put it the other way around
$$\text{Circumference} = \dfrac{4 \times \text{Area of the circle}}{\text{ diameter}}$$
As you see from this, there is no need for $\pi$ anywhere.

Comment: Great answer finally actually avoiding the $\pi$ :)

Comment: But P is not constant and depends on a which changes with every new value of n.  In the end we do not actually know the area of the circle.

Answer (score 22):

Recall:
$$A = \pi \left(\frac{D}{2}\right)^2$$
$$C = \pi D$$
Where $C$ is circumference, $A$ is area, and $D$ is diameter.

Thus:
$$\frac{A}{C} = \frac{\pi \left(\frac{D}{2}\right)^2}{\pi D}$$
The $\pi$'s cancel out, as well as one of the D's:
$$\frac{A}{C} = \frac{D}{4}$$

Solving for C:
$$C = \frac{4A}{D}$$

Comment: Tricky answer :) but if we just have D how we can calculate A without using pi?

Comment: vins: it will be awfully hard to calculate A without using pi since A is precisely pi*d!

Comment: Not difficult. There are two easy ways to approximate it, for the methods I say it's much better to do it with some program. One would be to use Montecarlo (2 random variables, x and y, with a module < R) and the other to integrate by parts $ y = \sqrt {r^2 - x^2} $ from 0 to r and multiply for 4

Comment: @StevenStadnicki It wouldn't be oh so hard... just define a new constant, say $\tau = \frac{C}{R}$  Now you can find the area in terms of $\tau$! :P

Comment: You could also start by saying: "Recall: A = C/D * (D/2)^2"  Since π is just defined as Circumference / Diameter."  But this answer is cheating because it assumes π and the area equation _a priori._

Answer (score 7):

Let's write down all our formulas:

$$A = \pi r^2 = 254.34$$
$$C = 2\pi r$$
$$d = 2r = 18$$

where $A$ is area, $r$ is radius, $C$ is circumference, and $d$ is diameter. We're trying to find the expression in the second; if we look at the first formula it's *almost* there, but it's missing a factor of 2 (easy to solve) and there's an extra factor of $r$. But if we divide the expression in the first formula by the expression in the third formula, we get

$$\frac{254.34}{18} = A/d = \frac{\pi r}{2}$$

Almost there! Now we just need to multiply by 4:

$$2 \pi r = 4\frac{\pi r}{2} = 4A/d = 4*\frac{254.43}{18} = 56.52.$$

Comment: @Sigur that would result in an an area smaller than the true area, not larger. His given area and diameter imply $\pi \approx 3.45$.

Comment: Wow, 4 equivalent answers but noone (including me) had noticed that the circle is impossible. Great caution there :)

Comment: Some times we see people using such strange values to approximate $\pi$. I'll not be surprised with this value, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $$\frac{4\times\text{Area}}{\text{Diameter}}=\frac{4\pi r^2}{2r}=2\pi r$$

Comment: Sorry this didn't give me the right answer

Comment: @DanielK, what is your right answer?

Comment: @DanielK Perhaps it didn't give you the right answer because your circle is impossible?

Comment: @DanielK: assuming that your area is $279.46\text{ cm}^2$ and the diameter is $18\text{ cm}$, we get the circumference to be
$$
\frac{4\times279.46\text{ cm}^2}{18\text{ cm}}=62.1\text{ cm}
$$
However, a circle with a diameter of $18\text{ cm}$ would have an area of $254.469\text{ cm}^2$

Comment: @DanielK I don´t understand, why are you asking if you already know the "right answer"?

Answer (score 5):

See  Approximation of circle by n-sided polygons in interative [Java Apllets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Applet) for Circle Area Approximation. For Exemple [here](http://geogebrainstituteph.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/circle-area-approximation.html).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since $A=\pi r^2$ then $A/r^2=\pi$. But $C=2\pi r$ and so $C=2r A/r^2=2A/r=4A/d$, where $d$ is the diameter.

Comment: So you're saying (Area x 2) divided by Diameter? Because if you are this also didn't give me the answer I was looking for

Comment: @DanielK:  It looks like you are a factor 2 off, but your data are not correct, either.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised no-one has yet given this answer, so:
$$C=\tau r=\frac{\tau}{2}d$$
So, no, you don't need $\pi$ ;)

Comment: Did you mean to write C instead of A?

Comment: @Martin You are right of course. Thanks for spotting this.

Answer (score 3):

The relation between area of a circle and its circunference can be seen by dissecting it, according to your tastes, as an [onion](http://www.mathteacherctk.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/1.jpg), or as a [pizza](http://blog.zacharyabel.com/tag/circles/).

Answer (score 2):

I think this answer might help also.

Suppose you know a priori that the only way to get what you want either by algorithms that approximate the area A of the circle area polígnos with n sides.

If you want an algorithm which does not mention the constant $\pi$ irrational then you may have a dozen algorithms that provide the area $A>0$ of the circle by approximation of areas  $A_{n_k}$ polignos of $n_k$ sides. Here $k$ indicates the $k$-th step of the algorithm. In general all these algorithms are the algorithm as a coneceitual as described below.

> **Conceptual algorithm**
>
> 1. **Initialization:** Set $k = 0$ and one (or more if you want) poligno $P_{n_k}$  with $n_k$ sides. A number $\epsilon> 0$, Area $A>0$ of the circle.
> 2. **Step Interactive:** some effective procedure that gets a poligno $P_{n_{k +1}}$ by polignos from the previous step that makes the sequence $ A_k $ of areas of polignos $P_{n_{k}}$  converges.
> 3. **Stopping criterion:** say something like $| A - A_{n_{k +1}} | <\epsilon$

If we do not have *a priori* the area $A>0$ of the circle  then such an conceptual algorithm is possible but a little more complex.

The answer to your question is then **yes** and **not**:

- **Yes**, by cause the conceptual algorithm not mentioned the irrational constant $\pi$.
- **Not**, by cause, for all above type algorithms work by  providing an indirect calculation for $\pi $.  To see this, just remember that the area of circle is  $$A = \pi\cdot  r^2.$$ And by any above type algorithms  $$\lim_{k\to\infty} A_{n_k} = A.$$ Then
  $$
  \pi = \frac{1}{r^2}\cdot\lim_{k\to\infty} A_{n_k}.
  $$

I hope that helped.